# Exclude classes from EMMA in Gradle build

Tags: build, code-coverage, gradle, emma

I build my project with Gradle 1.0 and I use the EMMA plugin for code coverage info. I would like to exclude certain files from the coverage report.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including this [Gradle script](https://github.com/breskeby/gradleplugins/blob/master/emmaPlugin/emma.gradle)? I think you can exclude classes within your instrumentation definition (see example below). However, it doesn't look like you can set the exclude pattern by using a convention property.

```
ant.emma(enabled: 'true', verbosity:'info'){
    instr(merge:"true", destdir: emmaInstDir.absolutePath, instrpathref:"run.classpath",
          metadatafile: new File(emmaInstDir, '/metadata.emma').absolutePath) {
        instrpath {
            fileset(dir:sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.absolutePath, includes:"**/*.class", excludes:"**/Some*.class")
        }
    }
}
```

If I were you I'd try to fork the plugin, add a new field to `EmmaPluginConvention` that lets you set the exclude pattern and then use that variable in the `instrpath` definition. After changing the code and verifying that it works send a pull request to the author. I am sure he will incorporate your change.

Comment: You are right. I forgot that the EMMA plugin is not an official one from Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work with gradle 1.5. Emma takes a filter like so:

```
ant.emma(enabled: 'true', verbosity: $verbosityLevel) {
        instr(merge: "true", destdir: emmaInstDir.absolutePath, instrpathref: "run.classpath",
                metadatafile: new File(emmaInstDir, '/metadata.emma').absolutePath, filter: "-com.someclass.*" ) {
            instrpath {
                fileset(dir: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir.absolutePath, includes: "**/*.class" )
            }
        }
    }
```

the filter follows the definition from this page:
http://emma.sourceforge.net/reference/ch02s06s02.html